# Detect when view has been dismissed (touched)

Tags: java, android

I'm using MaterialShowcaseView:
https://github.com/deano2390/MaterialShowcaseView

How can I detect if a **specific** ShowcaseView has been touched  (dismissed). In my activity, I have 3 ShowcaseViews.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may have misunderstood your question, but here goes.

If you make a custom View that extends ShowcaseView, you might be able to override `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)` and then put whatever functionality you need inside that method.

See this page about Views: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html